# GROUP BY continuous months in different years

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have one table (but at many locations):

```
DATE         STUFF
-------------------
2011-12-01   DATA
2011-12-02   DATA
2011-12-03   DATA
...
2011-12-31   DATA
2012-01-01   DATA
2012-01-02   DATA
```

My table covers multiple years from 2005 to 2012.  I want to get AGGREGATE Function values, i.e., SUM/AVG/MAX/MIN, for each month within each year.  Easy:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m')
```

I want go do the same for 3-month time periods within those years... this works for all but one:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m') IN (12, 01, 02)
```

My other time periods work, because they are in the same year (03, 04, 05), (06, 07, 08), and (09, 10, 11)... but the GROUP BY above is grouping December of 2012 with January/February of 2012.  My time period has to be December 2011 and January/February 2012, December 2010 and January/February 2011... ...

I want to keep this generic, so I don't have to update with date spans, in order to put the code in a stored procedure for multiple locations.

I've tried to join the table to it self by shifting the year ahead by one if MONTH 12.  This yielded undesirable results.

Comment: Create an artificial column called "Business Year" and add 1 to the current year if the month is December. You can then group by that. It makes sense to do this because your Year and your BusinessYear are two different (but related) concepts. I often do this for clients as they want to see both sets of dates, and it exposes how the grouping actually works. This is also often solved by the addition of an extra table - "BusinessMonth" which maps months onto quarters (that you then group and order by)

Answer (score 3):

```
 GROUP BY floor((month(DATE) + year(DATE) * 12 -1 + %month_shift%) / %month_group_period%)
```

where %month_group_period% is three (3) in your example
and   %month_shift%        is one (1) to obtain december, january, february together, and so on

**EDIT:**  this works for 5 month period too (if you want)

Comment: This is good, and probably as generic as you get. Can you add the SELECT part too, showing how to calculate back out the year and month of the period?

Comment: @lc, may be necesary a way back or not, DATE will be aggregate propely, but in case is enough `month(date), year(date)`

Comment: @LuisSiquot...for some reason I can not get this to work...  I get the same results I had before where it appears to be counting dec in the calendar year it appears.  This is what I have:  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%Y'), 
         DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%m') IN 
         (FLOOR(DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%m') + DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%y') * 12 - 2) * 12 / 3 ), 
     --    floor(month + year * 12) - 2 ) * 12 / 3)
         DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%m') IN (03, 04, 05),
         DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%m') IN (06, 07, 08), 
         DATE_FORMAT(d1.WX_DATE, '%m') IN (09, 10, 11)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a little bit here about what you really want to do with `DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m') IN (12, 01, 02)`, but:

```
SELECT IF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m') = 12, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y') + 1, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y')) AS yr, 
    CASE DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m')
        WHEN 12 THEN 1
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 2
        WHEN 4 THEN 2
        WHEN 5 THEN 2
        WHEN 6 THEN 3
        WHEN 7 THEN 3
        WHEN 8 THEN 3
        WHEN 9 THEN 4
        WHEN 10 THEN 4
        WHEN 11 THEN 4
    END AS qtr
FROM ...
GROUP BY IF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m') = 12, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y') + 1, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y')), 
    CASE DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m')
        WHEN 12 THEN 1
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 2
        WHEN 4 THEN 2
        WHEN 5 THEN 2
        WHEN 6 THEN 3
        WHEN 7 THEN 3
        WHEN 8 THEN 3
        WHEN 9 THEN 4
        WHEN 10 THEN 4
        WHEN 11 THEN 4
    END
```

Comment: + 1 Beat me to it, although personally, I'd put this in the SELECT list too, as it's useful for users to see.

Comment: @dash Yeah, I realized that and added the SELECT list, thanks.

Comment: this is far from "generic" as OP asked for, what if new group by requires nov,dec,jan ??

Comment: @LuisSiquot Personally, this would be in a table (business quarter) and I'd join onto it via the original month. You can then vary the content of this table if your reporting requirement changes.

Comment: @LuisSiquot I understood the OP's "generic" to mean it can be coded in the select query as opposed to having to update multiple tables with a new column, but perhaps I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `GROUP BY` how you are trying to do it.  You would probably want to write your queries like this

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as `month`, SUM(stuff) as `sum`
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date) IN ('2010', '2011', 2012')
GROUP BY `month`
```

The GROUP BY clause is not where you should be filtering/formatting your data.

Of course, you could use whatever aggregate function you want instead of SUM.  Also you can omit the WHERE clause for all years, or modify the years to be included as needed.

If you want year and month, you could simply modify the query like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as `year`, MONTH(date) as `month`, SUM(stuff) as `sum`
FROM table
WHERE `year` IN ('2010', '2011', 2012')
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract one month from the date for the group by:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_add(DATE,  interval 1 month), '%Y'),
         DATE_FORMAT(date_add(date, interval 1 month), '%m') IN (12, 01, 02)
```

You will probably also have to modify the select.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_add(date_add(DATE,  interval 1 month), interval -1 month), '%Y'),
       DATE_FORMAT(date_add(date_add(date, interval 1 month), interval -1 month), '%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(IF(MONTH(`DATE`)=12,DATE_ADD(`DATE`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR),`DATE`),'%Y')
       , DATE_FORMAT(`DATE`,'%m')
```

Basically, if month is 12, then add 1 year to it.

Actually, I would tend to do it something like this:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`DATE`,INTERVAL IF(MONTH(`DATE`)=12,1,0) YEAR),'%Y')
       , CASE WHEN MONTH(`DATE`) IN (12,1,2) THEN 1
              WHEN MONTH(`DATE`) IN (3,4,5) THEN 2
              WHEN MONTH(`DATE`) IN (6,7,8) THEN 3
              WHEN MONTH(`DATE`) IN (9,10,11) THEN 4
          END
```